# Difference between Nlohmann Json "array" and "array_t"

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

How is nlohmann **array_t** different from Nlohmann json **array**? How is **array_t** actually used?  The documentation for each is as follows.

[array](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/doxygen/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a2c8d8f5741aedadac8f3bffd8f2ce13e.html#a2c8d8f5741aedadac8f3bffd8f2ce13e)

> Creates a JSON array value from a given initializer list. That is, given a list of values a, b, c, creates the JSON value [a, b, c]. If the initializer list is empty, the empty array [] is created.

Example,

```
nlohmann::json j_nonempty_init_list = json::array({1, 2, 3, 4});
std::cout << j_nonempty_init_list;
// [1,2,3,4]
```

[array_t](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/doxygen/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a858c1cf8407bc06494e3a1114a3b73e7.html)

> To store objects in C++, a type is defined by the template parameters explained below.
>
> - **Template Parameters**
>
>   - **ArrayType** container type to store arrays (e.g., std::vector or std::list)
>   - **AllocatorType** allocator to use for arrays (e.g., std::allocator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json::array` is a static function that converts an initializer list into a `json` value with internal type `value_t::array`.

`array_t` is defined as follows:

```
using array_t = ArrayType<basic_json, AllocatorType<basic_json>>;
```

where `ArrayType` is a template template parameter to `basic_json`:

```
template<template<typename U, typename V, typename... Args> class ObjectType =
         std::map,
         template<typename U, typename... Args> class ArrayType = std::vector,
         class StringType = std::string, class BooleanType = bool,
         class NumberIntegerType = std::int64_t,
         class NumberUnsignedType = std::uint64_t,
         class NumberFloatType = double,
         template<typename U> class AllocatorType = std::allocator,
         template<typename T, typename SFINAE = void> class JSONSerializer =
         adl_serializer,
         class BinaryType = std::vector<std::uint8_t>>
class basic_json;
```

and finally `nlohmann::json` is just the default instantiation:

```
using json = basic_json<>;
```

So, `json::array_t` is in the end a type alias for `std::vector<json>`.
You can override the types passed to `basic_json` if you create your own typedef over `basic_json`.